# Kafka and Spark Streaming Simple Producer Consumer

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, producer-consumer

I do not know why the data sent by producer do not reach the consumer.
I am working on cloudera virtual machine.
I am trying to write simple producer consumer where the producer uses Kafka and consumer uses spark streaming.

The Producer Code in scala:

```
import java.util.Properties
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer._

object kafkaProducer {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val props = new Properties()
    props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
    props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
    props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")

    val producer = new KafkaProducer[String, String](props)

    val TOPIC = "test"

    for (i <- 1 to 50) {
      Thread.sleep(1000) //every 1 second
      val record = new ProducerRecord(TOPIC, generator.getID().toString(),generator.getRandomValue().toString())
      producer.send(record)
    }

    producer.close()
  }
}
```

The Consumer Code in scala :

```
import java.util

import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer

import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
import java.util.Properties

import kafka.producer._

import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.streaming._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka._

object kafkaConsumer {
      def main(args: Array[String]) {


        var totalCount = 0L
        val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[1]").setAppName("AnyName").set("spark.driver.host", "localhost")
        val ssc =  new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(2))
        ssc.checkpoint("checkpoint")
        val stream = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, "localhost:9092", "spark-streaming-consumer-group", Map("test" -> 1))

        stream.foreachRDD((rdd: RDD[_], time: Time) => {
          val count = rdd.count()
          println("\n-------------------")
          println("Time: " + time)
          println("-------------------")
          println("Received " + count + " events\n")
          totalCount += count
        })
        ssc.start()
        Thread.sleep(20 * 1000)
        ssc.stop()

        if (totalCount > 0) {
          println("PASSED")
        } else {
          println("FAILED")
        }
      }
}
```

Comment: I guess that you start producer and consumer sequentially ???

Comment: Yes, I start the consumer then the producer while the consumer is running.

Comment: Have you tested your producer code by a console consumer and your consumer code by a console producer? Kafka - Spark integration can get tricky...

Comment: I have tested the producer code by a console consumer but have not tested the consumer code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is resolved by changing in the consumer code the line :

```
        val stream = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, "localhost:9092", "spark-streaming-consumer-group", Map("test" -> 1))
```

the second parameter should be the zookeeper port which 2181 not 9092 and the zookeeper will manage to connect to the Kafka port 9092 automatically.

Note: Kafka should be started from terminal before running both the producer and consumer.